# OSX: How to filter out the menu bar from CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo

Tags: macos, core-graphics

I'm using CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo to grab the list of windows on the desktop. I'd like to filter out only the visible windows using values of the [Window List keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/reference/CGWindow_Reference/Constants/Constants.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/%29). The one window I'm having trouble is the OSX menu bar. One solution I've thought of using is looking at the X and Y of the window bounds. No visible windows seem to have both of those equal to 0, but I'm not sure how reliable this method is.

One other way to do this would be to compare the PID number to that of the OSX Window Server, but I'm not sure how to get that. Can anyone point me towards the right API or know of a reliable way to filter out the menu bar?

Edit: I have the same code as kondy below with the following additions since the listOptions themselves aren't good enough:

```
CGRect windowBounds;
CGRectMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation((CFDictionaryRef) [windowInfo objectForKey:(id)kCGWindowBounds], &windowBounds);

if (!(windowBounds.origin.x == 0 && windowBounds.origin.y == 0))
{
    // Work with windows that aren't the Menubar
}
```

Comment: I ended up going with checking the window bounds and seeing if both x and y were equal to 0. This post tells you how to get the window bounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593710/get-a-bounds-of-windowref

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer to filter out the "Window Server":

```
CGWindowListOption listOptions = kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly | kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements;
CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(listOptions, kCGNullWindowID);
```

Using these ORed options, I get a result as same as mac's "Windowed processes" in "Activity Manager"

I hope it will help you!

Comment: I have the same code with some additions (edited the original answer).