# How to tell which screen a CGWindow is shown on when it is partially off-screen?

Tags: macos, window, core-graphics, screen

I get a list of `CGWindow`s using `CGWindowListCreate` as shown below:

```
CFArrayRef windows = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, 0);
```

Is there a way to tell which `NSScreen` each window is on? I've trying looking at the intersection of window bounds and the frames of the screens, but if a window is partially off screen it can intersect with the frame of another screen.

Is there a more reliable way to do this?

Comment: Just a thought,Can't you check the window frame?

Comment: What would I check it for?

Comment: I think that window bounds can obtained by this method:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593710/get-a-bounds-of-windowref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593710/get-a-bounds-of-windowref). After this get the screen bounds using CGDisplayBounds. Check window frames are within display rect or not.

Comment: I can get the bounds, but as I said in the question, when a window is partially offscreen its bounds will be within the frame of multiple screens.

Comment: When window is partially offscreen what is the bounding rect you get and what is the display rect.

Comment: I can only get the bounds (as described in your link), and they are the full window bounds in global co-ordinates.

Comment: Did you found any solution ? I'm currently having the same problem,

Comment: No, sorry. Still no way to do this as far as I know.